# Disable/Enable internet inside docker container

Tags: docker, ubuntu, playwright

I want to control internet connectivity inside the docker container. This is so I can run e2e tests that need the internet to be turned off and back on again.

I cannot use `--privileged` this is not allowed in my ci pipeline. With `privileged` I use `ifconfig eth0 down/up` to control internet connectivity.

I am using `mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:focal` It is an Ubuntu base image.

My tests are using `playwright` it is for `electron` I can't any APIs that simulate internet connectivity either.

Comment: so you want a Docker-only solution? aren't you interested turn off the network inside the browser (e.g via Chrome DevTools)? in an e2e test, I'd go that way for clarity.

Comment: chrome solution is not enough for me. I am testing mqtt reconnection.

Comment: No sure if this will work - but could you update `hosts` file with your script? - update the DNS for your site to be IP `172.0.0.1`  - that would stop it connecting.

Comment: I have tried that. Changing the hosts file does not break existing connections. What did now is to `ufw` on the docker host to block internet traffic from the container. it will best to use the firewall inside the container to deny internet traffic but I don't know how to do it.